# In what context do we use "subject to"?

Tags: verbs

I came across a situation where a customer had agreed to pay a certain amount but in the contract it was mentioned "Rates are subject to particular charges."

So when we say "rates are subject to particular charges," does it mean rates are calculated excluding those particular charges?

Comment: That sentence doesn't quite make sense. Are you sure it doesn't say 'subject to chaNges' not 'chaRges'?

Answer (score 1):

The term *subject to* is used as an adjective. It has several related [meanings](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subject?q=subject%20to)

> 1 likely or prone to be affected by (a particular condition or occurrence, typically an unwelcome or unpleasant one):
>   *he was subject to bouts of manic depression*
>
> 2 dependent or conditional upon:
>   *the proposed merger is subject to the approval of the shareholders*
>
> 3 under the authority of:
>   *ministers are subject to the laws of the land*

In the context of your sentence, the first definition seems most apt, meaning

> Rates are *subject to* [likely to be affected by] particular charges.

Charges are requirements to pay, so these rates will be *increased* by those charges